# Why is it saying callback is not defined?

Tags: javascript, json, callback, jsfiddle

I have made a server for a game I am making, and it generates a map for me, but on this test client I am making, it's not working correctly.

I add the site as a script, and it's working fine as a script, but when the javascript on jsfiddle is read, it says that the function callback() is not define, but it clearly is, and it should be sending the map object to the console, but it's just erroring out... :/

Here's the link to the JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tgwizman/9QrUF/

I hope you guys can figure it out, because I'm totally lost as to why it isn't working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your jsfiddle the javascript callback function is defined after you loaded the map with your javascript include, and at that point your callback is not yet defined.

Here is a fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRXEB/).

Example source:

```
<script>
var map;

function callback(cb) {
    map = cb;
    console.log(map);
}
</script>
<script src='http://mmorpg_server.jit.su/?map=0,0'></script>​
```

Comment: You're right, my mistake, I forgot that `<script>` tags are blocking. Edit your answer so I can revote

Answer (score 3):

change dropdown value to `no wrap (head)`

[image: screen shot]

http://jsfiddle.net/9QrUF/3/

Answer (score 2):

[The callback must be defined before the map is loaded](http://jsfiddle.net/9QrUF/2/). otherwise, you are calling an undefined function. external scripts may download in any order, but are executed in the order they are coded into the page.

```
<script>
    var map;
    //declare callback first before anything uses it
    function callback(cb) {
        map = cb;
        console.log(map);
    }
</script>

//this calls the callback it MUST be loaded after
<script src='http://mmorpg_server.jit.su/?map=0,0'></script>​
```

Comment: This is incorrect as the file is loaded **way** after the function gets defined, since it's getting the data via an request. The real reason for it is due to jsfiddle

Comment: yeah, because in your case it's not in a closure. view source on the original fiddle

Comment: and your point? a fiddle is a demo. not the actual code. if you are going to code it right, then do it right. not reply on parameters in a demo environment.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, I forgot that `<script>` tags are blocking. Edit your answer so I can revote

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's because jsFiddle doesn't always work perfectly.</strike>

### [Here's a fiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/2PvwN/)

it happens because jsfiddle wraps the script elements in their own wrappers (closures) and therefore can't access any functions declared in them

Never mind, [KARASZI István's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160166/465546) and [Joseph's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160157/465546) answers are better

Comment: In your fiddle, the callback function is defined before the map loading, check the source of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;

function callback(cb)
 {
    map = cb;
    console.log(map);
}
</script>
<script src='http://mmorpg_server.jit.su/?map=0,0'> 
</script>​
```

Hope this will work !!!